# How to return the last value in Q javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Hi there im new to writing promises in javascript. I want to return a value from func1 which are composed of then (using q) calling other functions resolving the value then passing to through the next function. The problem is i want to return the last value in func 1. So I can use it in caller function. But init value just returns undefined. 
Here are the codes:

```js
function func1(string1, string2) {
  othermodule
    .otherfunc1(string1)
    .then(function(outputstring1) {
      var params = othermodule.otherfunc2(outputstring1,string2);
      return params;
    })
    .then(anotherfunc)
    .then(anotherfunc2)
    .then(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
       // outputs data
       return data;
    });
}

function caller() {
  var initValue = 0;
  initValue = func1(string1,string2);
  console.log('init value = '+initValue);
  //init value = undefined
}
```

Comment: In this case i want to return data such that initValue = data

Comment: promises do not make asynchronous code synchronous ...

Comment: how to resolve then?

Answer (score 3):

Writing asynchronous code in javascript is *poisonous*, meaning all code calling async code must be async itself.

Your code can be rewritten to:

```
function func1(string1, string2) {
    return Q.fcall(othermodule.otherfunc1, string1)
        .then(function(outputstring1) {
            var params = othermodule.otherfunc2(outputstring1, string2);
            return params;
        })
        .then(anotherfunc)
        .then(anotherfunc2)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
}

function caller() {
    return func1(string1, string2).then(function(initValue) {
        console.log('init value = ' + initValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of using Q.fcall? isn't it just the same?

Comment: also this gives out unexpected token return on the return func1

Comment: `Q.fcall` seems superfluous in this code as `othermodule.otherfunc1` already returns a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX I wasn't sure that `othermodule.otherfunc1` returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Return the promise in func1

and use .then in caller to get the "returned" value

```
function func1(string1, string2) {
    return othermodule.otherfunc1(string1)
        .then(function(outputstring1) {
            var params = othermodule.otherfunc2(outputstring1, string2);
            return params;
        })
        .then(anotherfunc)
        .then(anotherfunc2)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
}

function caller() {
    func1(string1, string2).then(function(initValue) {
        console.log('init value = ' + initValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry got it now I forgot to put return on the othermodule.otherfun1(string1) thanks! :)

Comment: the problem is I want to get the data outside the promise. Is there no method to return this? If I do the way you did then I will still be inside the promise.

Comment: You have to deal with the asynchronous nature of the code - you can't turn it synchronous. Embrace the asynchronous nature of javascript, it's not that hard to change how you code

Comment: @user1727843 - is there a problem with the answer or how you are using it?